# calculationg time diffrence between a server and a client device with diffrenet time zones in ios

Tags: ios, facebook, date, datetime, nsdateformatter

I have to show time difference between two posts as like `Instagram` and `Facebook`. Like the post added in 1 HR, post added 30 MIN.

I have problem with  different time zone. I have to compare user device date-time with server post date-time. Also some time created problem with time format 12 HR/24 HR.
Any body guide me, How to handle this problem. Any reference for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to use same timezone in server for all time related stuffs.

Use UTC time and do whatever +/- for your current location you want to do. This will be effective throughout the timezones.

Don't store 7:30 IST, or 5:37 PST in server, it will become too difficult to get the exact time as you will be requiring different dateformatters to convert to a common timezone.

Answer (score 0):

Well, obviously you need to know the timezones you're dealing with.  Then you can create an NSTimeZone object for each, take the `secondsFromGmt` property of each NSTimeZone object, and subtract to determine the difference.  (Obviously, seconds difference must be converted to minutes and hours.)

To parse a date into NSDate form you need to use NSDateFormatter.  (There are thousands of examples of how to do this here and on the web, so please do some research before asking how to use NSDateFormatter.  We're quite tired of answering the same questions again and again and again and again.)